# MySQL for Excel exporting incorrectly formats dates

Tags: mysql, excel

I am trying to export an Excel sheet to a MySQL table. I asked to create a new table and insert the data from excel.

Using Excel 2013, brand new MySQL for Excel add-in, and brand new MySQL (running on my desktop in Windows 7).

At first I would get the error message

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near
>   ':00:00,10:00:00,9/1/2010,12/20/2010,'HEIEUS','K2I4','M',0,0,3,'X','PP','2010-11-'
>   at line 4

After pasting the SQL statement into a MySQL Workbench query I was told there was a missing parentheses right in front of a date.

I figured out that if I added quotes around the date (in DateTime format), that line would be read in and the error would move a line down to the next row insertion. Examples I have seen do show that the date text should be inside quotes (https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/databases/mysql/insert-date/).

It is impractical for me to copy the sql statement, paste into MySQL Workbench, then add quotes to all the dates for thousands of rows. Does anyone know of a way to get Excel to format the dates correctly. Or has anyone even seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, because it works around the MySQL plugin for Excel which should be working.  You can try exporting your data from Excel as CSV.  Make certain that every column is quoted when you export it.

Then import the data into MySQL using `LOAD DATA`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```